# grails - display flash message

Tags: grails

I’m new to Grails, and I have a question that should be easy for most of you.

I have a page displaying an `object` list. I want to display a message if there’s a `DataIntegrityViolation` when an `object` is deleted. What I’m doing is:

```
def delete() {

    def instanceToDelete= Myobject.get(params.id)
    try {
        instanceToDelete.delete(flush: true)
        redirect(action: "list", id: params.id)
    }
    catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        flash.message = "some message"
        //I want to refresh the div containing the flash.message here
    }
}
```

Here is where the flash message should be displayed:

```
  <g:if test="${flash.message}">
  <div class="alert alert-error" style="display: block">${flash.message}</div>
```

Sorry — I know it’s a silly question, but I really can't find a solution.

Comment: What is the question about? It seems that code correct and you will see "some message" string on view if DataIntegrityViolationException is caught.

Comment: the problem is i don't see it

Comment: I see now. You are talking about styles. A bit misunderstanding (=

Comment: No, i don't think the problem is the style.

Comment: The problem is **there is no redirect in `catch` block**. In the `try`, if everything goes well, you redirect to `list.gsp`. but in `catch` **you don't render any view to handle flash object**.

Answer (score 23):

The `flash` object is a `Map` which stores key/value pairs, so you can define your own key for error messages. For example:

```
try {
    instanceToDelete.delete(flush: true)            
    flash.message = "successfully deleted object"
 }
 catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
    flash.error = "could not delete object"            
 }
redirect(action: "list", id: params.id)
```

Then you can check the `flash` object containing the `error` key, and use a different style for that kind of message:

```
<g:if test="${flash.error}">
  <div class="alert alert-error" style="display: block">${flash.error}</div>
</g:if>
<g:if test="${flash.message}">
  <div class="message" style="display: block">${flash.message}</div>
</g:if>
```

Comment: How can i display the message without redirecting? Basically I don't want to redirect to list because there i reload the list of objects and if i don't delete anything i don't need to reload.

Comment: You can't modify client data without a browser reload (server redirect / forward) unless you're submitting your requests via Ajax.

Answer (score 6):

```
// backend code example

def save () { 
    if(params.name) { 
          . 
          . 
      object.save(); 
      flash.message =  "Saved successfully" 
    } 
    else { 
        flash.message = "Saved fail"
    }

// HTML example

<g:if test="${flash.message}">
   <div class="update_message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
</g:if>
```

Comment: Suggestion for improvement of your comments: Add some words on what is the key part of this code, what it does and why it's best done that way.

Answer (score 3):

This can help you:

```
def delete() {
    def instanceToDelete= Myobject.get(params.id)
    try {
        instanceToDelete.delete(flush: true)
        flash.success = "Object deleted correctly"
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        flash.error = "Something goes wrong"
    }
    redirect(action: "list", id: params.id)
}
```

redirect to the gsp after all the code, to can store if there is an error or everything goes well.

you can put the messages in different variable to discriminate between error and success.

```
<g:if test="${flash.success}">
    <div class="alert alert-success" style="display: block">${flash.success}</div>
</g:if>
<g:if test="${flash.error}">
    <div class="alert alert-error" style="display: block">${flash.error}</div>
</g:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

Strict answer : Just return your message (or render with a model map)

for your controller :

```
def delete() {

    def instanceToDelete= Myobject.get(params.id)
    try {
        instanceToDelete.delete(flush: true)
        redirect(action: "list", id: params.id)
    }
    catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        render view:'delete', model:[message: "some message"]
        //I want to refresh the div containing the flash.message here
    }
}
```

for your gsp :

```
<g:if test="${message}">
    <div class="alert alert-error" style="display: block">${message}</div>
```

But Gregg is right, you should **never** modify client data without a `redirect`.
If you do, the user might refresh (or come back to) the same url, and attempt again same action accidentally. You should really do like in hitt5's answer.