# How to add validation for file type in grails

Tags: validation, grails, file-upload, groovy

I have a domain object with following:

```
class Color {
  String name
  String fileLocation

  static constraints = {
    name (nullable: false, blank: false)
  }
}
```

In my controller I'm doing the following:

```
def save() {
  def colorInstance = new Color(params)
  if (colorInstance.save(flush: true)) {
    def file = request.getFile("myfile")
    if (!file.empty && uploadService.isFileAllowed(file)) {
      uploadService.uploadFile(file, file.originalName, "folderName")
    }
  }
  else {
    render (view: "create", model: [coorInstance: colorInstance])
  }
}
```

This all works fine however, I'm not sure how to throw an error when the uploaded file isn't what is allowed. i.e. `uploadService.isFileAllowed(file)` returns `false` ??

How can I throw an error back to the user saying

> Uploaded file isn't allowed

when `uploadService.isFileAllowed(file)` returns false ?

Note:

The `isFileAllowed` method is reading first few bytes of a file to determine what type of file it is.

Comment: Really depends on the relationship between Color and the file. Explain in detail what `uploadService.uploadFile` does

Comment: that method saves the file in a folder and returns the absolute path of the saved file. that path is saved in the `fileLocation` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if `isFileAllowed` returns false or the file is empty, it will add an error to the colorInstance to the fileLocation property. It will only upload the file if the colorInstance validates successfully (to prevent files uploaded for unsaved objects).

As a side note, I prefer saving files in tables partly for this reason. It makes validation much less clunky and its impossible to have a disconnect between your objects and the files. - Just my 2c.

```
  def save() {

  def colorInstance = new Color(params)

    def file = request.getFile("myfile")
    if (!file.empty && uploadService.isFileAllowed(file)) {
      if (colorInstance.validate()) {
        uploadService.uploadFile(file, file.originalName, "folderName")
      }
    }
    else {
      colorInstance.errors.rejectValue('fileLocation','error.message.code.here')
    }

  if (colorInstance.save(flush: true)) {
     //do whatever here
  }
  else {
    render (view: "create", model: [coorInstance: colorInstance])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you save an error message to flash memory and then render it on the page if it exists?  [See this post for help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14278214/1676002).

```
if (!file.empty && uploadService.isFileAllowed(file)) {
  uploadService.uploadFile(file, file.originalName, "folderName")
} else {
    flash.error = "Uploaded file isn't allowed"
}
```

Comment: Flash Message is a good recommendation. However, to throw the error back without knowing about "flass message magic" in Grails, birdy can simply render the previous view with a new model which contains the error. It's also ok

Answer (score 1):

apply this login in your controller

```
String fileName = "something.ext";
        int a = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
        String extName = fileName.substring(a);
        System.out.println(fileName.substring(a));
        ArrayList<String> extList = new ArrayList<String>();
        extList.add("jpg");
        extList.add("jpeg");
        extList.add("png");
        if(extList.contains(extName))
        {
            System.out.println("proceed");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("throw exception");
        }
```

Comment: This is an answer for the question title, but not for the question.